# java.io.File getting extra char while writing into file

Tags: java, io

Why I am getting extra char while writing into file for the following code? If I am using `writeBytes(String)` than the below code is working file. Then what is the problem with `dos.writeChars()` method?

```
File fileObj = new File("student.txt");

try {

  // writing into file
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileObj);
  String msg = "This is student file";

  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
  dos.writeChars(msg);

  //reading from file
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileObj);
  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

  System.out.println(dis.readLine());

  for (int i = 0; ((i = dis.read()) != -1); i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
  }

  fos.close();
  dos.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.err.println("File not found!");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? What output are you getting?

Comment: I am expecting "This is student file", but I am getting some extra char after every char like T[]h[]i[]s[]....

Comment: For starters, close the outputstream before you open the inputstream.

Comment: I did but the same result persists.

Comment: Take a look at the answer @Erik Ekman gave you.

Comment: I got my answer, but i am confused with the size of string before writing into file and after writing into file

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeChars()` uses 2-byte chars (UTF-16). So each char you write will result in two bytes written.

If you want another encoding use `getBytes()` on the `String` and write it as bytes.

Comment: If you want to continue to use UTF-16, you can always prefix the output with the UTF-16 byte order mark (`0xFEFF`). This will trigger your text editor to read the bytes correctly.

Comment: suppose i am writing some String like "This is student file" then its size is 20bytes and when i am using writeChars() then it will write 40bytes of data. My ques actually is, what is the size of string before writing and after writing into file.

Comment: In Java, a `String` is built up from `char`s, which are 2 bytes each. So the string has been 20 chars and 40 bytes all the time.

Comment: i did not understand Erik what do you mean by "you can always prefix the output with the UTF-16 byte order mark (0xFEFF)" please elaborate

Comment: The byte order mark is used to tell the reader the encoding and endianness of the coming data. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Erik means that you can leave a clue for certain text editors which know to look for it.  But even if they can read the file, other simple/legacy software would probably choke on it, so the validity of that solution depends on what will be consuming the file.  The getBytes() solution from the answer itself would produce something more like a plain ascii text file.

Comment: Yes, and if lots of strings are to be written I would recommend using an `OutputStreamWriter` instead of `DataOutputStream` to only have to specify the encoding once.

Comment: thanks Chris and Erik. Got my ans. :)